# Reading from a growing file c++ still has problems

Tags: c++

I need to read from a growing file in C++, and found this page - [How to read a growing text file in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757304/how-to-read-a-growing-text-file-in-c).  I tested the Answer from there posted by @hmjd.  For testing purpose, I wrote a simple c++ code to read a large file and then write it to file every 0.3 seconds so that the file will be growing.  In the meantime, while the growing file was generating, I used hmjd's code to test reading it.  The first answer staring with if(ifs.seekg(p)) does not work at all, and the second answer starting with 'if(ifs.is_open())' works, but the loop will never end.

Comment: Show us your code for reading the file or relax and let us enter your brain with our psychic powers ....

Comment: Did you look at the answers for that question, or just use the code from the question?

Comment: I added my solution to the answers of the question you linked: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31977550/3807729

Comment: @Galik Thank you so much, this is a better version with 'seekg' and 'tellg'.  It works as the same behavior as what hmjd provided, after the growing file stop growing, your code hangs.

Answer (score 0):

This might be overly simplified, but couldn't you just close your handle to the file after it's grown and reopen a new file descriptor?