# Get live data from export option on program.

Tags: c++, windows, data-extraction

I want to know if there's a way, or if its even possible, to get live data from another program. So there's this software that logs data in real time, you then have the option to retrieve that data through a csv file that contains a time stamp and value by exporting it. I want that data live, basically to be exported continually into that text file so I can use it in a C++ program. I know this a vague question, but is there any possible way of doing this?

Comment: Write data in app A and read it in app B? Can't you do this on your own? Or use [IPC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: This answer may (or may not) be of use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757304/how-to-read-a-growing-text-file-in-c/31977550#31977550

Comment: ill look into IPC, along the lines of what i want, thank you.